# IOS unsetting the TabBar Controller

Tags: ios, cocoa

I have a TabBar, with a few Items, represting a view, now, when i load a view via one of the items, i want to unset the TabBar, not remove it, but set it to no item selected.

The TabBar Controller is made and initialized via storyboard, i asume i need to get its instance to do this, how would i go about doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by unset?

Comment: Show no selected Tab Indexes

Comment: Then which view controller will you show

Comment: Why would you want to do this? How is the user supposed to know which controller he's in if one of the tabs isn't highlighted? This probably goes against the HIG.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should just put the same image for both status selected and normal... if you unselect the selection you won't be able to show the view